# Extension entry point for both testing and deployment

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm closing in on the development of a VS Code extension, so I started to experiment with packaging and publishing. With *webpack* set up, my `package.json` now points to

```
"main": "./dist/extension",
```

as the packed-minified delopyment file is in the `dist` folder. Yet, to keep testing the extension, it should be

```
"main": "./out/extension",
```

And I don't mean unit testing and similar, just running with debugging from VS Code. How can I reconcile the difference without manually changing back and forth every time?